# Is this treatment of int64_t a GCC AND Clang bug?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, clang, posix

Now, some of you will be tempted to shout **undefined behaviour**, but there's a problem. The type `int64_t` is NOT defined by the C standard but by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html). POSIX defines this type as:

> a signed integer type with width N, no padding bits, and a two's-complement representation.

It does not leave this for the implementation to define and most definitely does NOT allow it to be treated as an unbounded integer.

```
linux$ cat x.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int stupid (int64_t a) {
  return (a+1) > a;
}

int main(void)
{
    int v;
    printf("%d\n", v = stupid(INT64_MAX));
    exit(v);
}

linux$ gcc -ox x.c -Wall && ./x
0
linux$ gcc -ox x.c -Wall -O2 && ./x # THIS IS THE ERROR.
1
linux$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

linux$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.14.13-0-amd64 #1 SMP Sat Jul 26 20:03:23 BST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
linux$ getconf LONG_BIT
32
linux$
```

Obviously, there's a problem here ... what is it?
Have I missed some sort of implicit cast ?

Comment: *The type `int64_t` is NOT defined by the C standard* - it is

Comment: Try adding to GCC flags -Wextra -pedantic -ansi please ? There is more undefined behavior protection.

Comment: @Christoph is correct, see `C11 7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types`: "These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names".

Comment: @Aracthor, -Wextra -pedantic give no additional commentary. Nor does adding -ansi too.

Comment: Just because POSIX says it's gotta be two's compliment with 64 bits and no padding doesn't mean it doesn't have undefined behavior if it overflows. I don't see anywhere on that page that defines the behavior if `INT64_MAX` is exceeded.

Comment: Your quote is about the representation, not about the behavior of operators. Do you have another one?

Comment: @Christoph, paxdiablo Hmm, okay. But if GCC is a POSIX compiler too it should be complying with the POSIX standard too. That most explicitly states that these types must be twos-complement. Therefor this defines the previously undefined behaviour, does it not ?

Comment: @user3710044, the fact that the types are well defined is irrelevant. In fact, _ISO_ defines them the same way. That _doesn't_ change the fact that an expression that results in a value outside the representable range is _still_ UB. In other words, locking down the representation does not lock down the behaviour. If you want the dry boring details from the standard (ISO), have a look over my answer.

Comment: @user3710044: Two's complement just means we use ordinary (left-infinite) binary numerals, except rather than the convention of representing a negative number as applying unary negation to a positive integer, we represent them directly with the numerals beginning with (infinitely) repeated `1`s instead. (and the only prefixes we allow are repeated `0` and repeated `1`, because we are dealing with ordinary integers rather than rational numbers with odd denominator or more general 2adic integers) 64 bits using sign extension is not enough precision to store `2^63`.

Comment: @Hurkyl: You can't actually "represent them directly" with a left-infinite encoding, you need the MSB to have a negative value for a direct representation, and that only happens if there is an MSB.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The 2-adic numeral `...11111` has value -1. With N bits of precision and sign extension, the most significant stored bit represents the prefix to be repeated infinitely to the left.

Comment: @BenVoigt: In case this needs further explanation, you can verify this by adding `...001` to `...111` to get `...000` (in both cases, `...` means to repeat the leading digit infinitely). Those really interested in this should look into the 2-adic numbers, although that's not really needed if you're just interested in +, -, and *. While, as you allude to, the notion of sign doesn't make sense for 2-adic numbers, when representing an ordinary integer 2-adically it's easy enough to recover the sign by checking which digit gets repeated on the left.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Oh I agree that is equivalent.  I just dispute that it can be called "direct representation".  BTW, you can't add `....001` to `...111` in your system, because the result is `1000...0000`, which is not representable in your system (its leading digit does not repeat infinitely... oops)  Truncated versions of your system all "do the right thing", however, and have a direct meaning where the value of the MSB is `-2**(N-1)` instead of `2**(N-1)` as it is in unsigned binary.

Comment: @Ben: You're making the same mistake people make when they think `1.000...` - `0.999...` results in `0.000...1`. There _isn't_ a place on the left for an extra `1` to appear, all the places get filled with `0`.

Comment: @Hurkyl: But `1.000....` - `0.999....` does equal `0.000....0001`, which is infinitesimally close to zero.  On the other hand `1000...000` is not zero, not even close.  Remember you're using an infinite system, so there's always another digit further to the left.

Comment: @Ben: Explaining how numerals work would be going to far afield, so I'll just leave this link here (this article also discusses left-infinite numerals too in the "p-adic number" section). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to go to POSIX to sort this out, ISO C controls this particular aspect in toto (references below are to the `C11` standard).

The rest of this answer is going to go all "language lawyer" to show why it's undefined behaviour to add one to your signed value and therefore why *both* answers (true *and* false) are valid.

---

First, your contention that `int64_t` is not defined in ISO is not really correct. Section `7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types` states, when referring to `intN_t` types, that:

> The typedef name `intN_t` designates a signed integer type with width *N*, no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus, `int8_t` denotes such a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.
>
> These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it *shall* define the corresponding typedef names.

That's why you don't need to worry about POSIX defining those types in a certain way, since ISO defines them exactly the same (two's complement, no padding, etc) assuming it has the appropriate capabilities.

---

So, now that we've established ISO *does* define them (if they're available in the implementation), let's now look at `6.5 Expressions /5`:

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined.

Adding two identical integral types will definitely give you the *same* type (at least at the rank of `int64_t`, well above the point where integer promotions are done<sup>1</sup>), since this is dictated by the usual arithmetic conversions specified in `6.3.1.8`. After the section dealing with various floating point types (of which `int64_t` is not), we see:

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.

Earlier in that same section you find the statement that dictates the type of the *result* once a common type has been found:

> Unless explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of the result.

So, given that the result of `INT64_MAX+1` won't actually fit into a `int64_t` variable, the behaviour is undefined.

---

Based on your comments that the encoding of `int64_t` indicates that adding one *would* wrap, you have to understand that *doesn't* change the clause that it's undefined at all. An implementation is still free to do whatever it wants in this case, even if that doesn't make sense based on what you think.

And, in any case, the expression `INT64_MAX + 1 > INT64_MAX` (where `1` undergoes the integer promotion to an `int64_t`) may well be simply compiled as `1` since that's arguably faster to do than actually incrementing a value and doing a comparison. And it *is* the correct result, since *anything* is the correct result :-)

In that sense, it's no different to an implementation converting:

```
int ub (int i) { return i++ * i++; } // big no-no
:
int x = ub (3);
```

into the simpler and almost certainly faster:

```
int x = 0;
```

You may *contend* that the answer would be better as `9` or `12` (depending on when the `++` side effects are performed) but, given undefined behaviour is a breaking of the contract between coder and compiler, the compiler is free to do whatever it wants.

---

In any case, if you want a *well defined* version of your function, you could simply opt for something like:

```
int stupid (int64_t a) {
    return (a == INT64_MAX) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

That gets you the desired/expected result *without* resorting to undefined behaviour :-)

---

<sup>1</sup> There *may* be an edge case here if the width of `int` is actually greater than 64 bits. In that case, it may well be that the integer promotions will force `int64_t` to an `int`, allowing the expression to be well defined. I haven't looked into that in great detail so may be wrong (in other words, don't consider it a gospel part of my answer) but it's worth keeping in mind as something to check if you ever get an implementation with an `int` more than 64 bits wide.

Comment: "Adding two identical integral types will definitely give you the same type" is actually not true, as the usual promotions are performed.  However, the conversion rank of the types in this case prevents promotion.

Comment: @user3528438, yes, good point, but all that means is that it will be promoted to `int64_t` if `int` is a lesser rank. The common type will still end up being `int64_t`.

Comment: Okay, bods, I _think_ I've covered all those issues in the most recent edit. Happy to hear any other constructive criticism that you may want to give.

Comment: Okay, I strongly disagree with this interpretation; as I mentioned in another comment. The C standard has the type of the arithmetic operation following the types of the arguments to the operation. This would mean that the operation in question is a 64bit two complement addition and so it is well defined for all values. It is not an unknown (hence undefined) choice  of one of the three values that C11 defines. Nevertheless, it does seem to be exactly the rationalisation that the complier writers are using.

Comment: @user3710044: well defined by the usual rules of two's complement _arithmetic,_ but ISO really only specifies two's complement _representation._  Given the fact ISO _specifically_ states that what you're doing is UB, you cannot be surprised when it turns around and bites you :-) When compiling at higher optimisation levels, I would say `gcc` is simply taking the view of giving the _fastest_ valid result since _all_ results are equally valid (as I stated in the answer).

Comment: @user3710044: Two's complement addition is not "well defined" at all.  There are plenty of hardware implementations of *saturating* two's-complement addition.

Comment: @BenVoigt, heh, the who point of the weird format known as two-complement is that additive arithmetic is done by the same hardware as modulo arithmetic. If it saturates, you're doing it wrong, it's not two-complement arithmetic, just 'representation'. So that appears to be the key word in section 7.20.1.1 --- Thank you everyone.

Comment: @user3710044: No, the whole point of two's complement is that no special handling is required for signed values, except on the sign bit itself.  Compare to addition on sign-magnitude representation, where different logic is required when the sign bits agree vs when they differ.

Comment: If `int` is a 64-bit integer, it *will* have higher rank than `int64_t`, so "conversion" would occur. It would, however, be irrelevant.

Comment: @BenVoigt, yes, no special handling of sign bit, the hardware for unsigned addition and two-complement signed addition is identical. So you don't need a signed integer adder circuit.  Unlike sign&magnitude or a saturating variant of twos complement.

Comment: @user3710044: The hardware for unsigned saturating addition and two's-complement saturating addition is also as good as identical.  The only difference is whether saturation is triggered by the carry flag or the overflow flag.  You could even argue that carry flag vs overflow flag is a minor difference between the unsigned modular addition and two's-complement modular addition... but in practice the circuit simply generates both.

Answer (score 9):

I'm still going to shout **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR**.

The reasoning here is simple, the compiler assumes that you're a perfect programer and would *never* write any code that could possibly result in undefined behavior.

So when it sees your function :

```
int stupid (int64_t a) {
  return (a+1) > a;
}
```

It assumes that you're never going to call it with `a==INT64_MAX`, because that would be UB.

Therefore, this function can trivially be optimized to :

```
int stupid (int64_t a) {
  return 1;
}
```

Which can then be inlined as appropriate.

I suggest you read [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) for more explanations of how compilers exploit UB for optimizations purposes.

Comment: I read it and I see that signed integer is overflow is NOT defined for the C standard, I'm not denying that it's undefined for C but for this to be a POSIX compliant compiler it must follow the POSIX standard too, which says explicitly says twos-Complement are you trying to claim that GCC is NOT a POSIX compiler ?

Comment: The *format* being 2s-complement for a particular type doesn't mean that *overflow* is 2s-complement for a particular operation. The compiler is free to assume that `INT64_MAX+1` produces a magic result which allows its optimisation to be valid.

Comment: @tux3 The C standard does not take precedence, it is more of a fallback. Posix would be perfectly entitled to define the behavior of integer overflow. It is only because (as far as I can see) it doesn't, that what C says is the right answer.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yes, that was very poorly formulated. I meant to say that in this case POSIX's definition was not contradicting the fact that this was still int overflow and still UB. I'll just remove that comment and let the others explain it better.

Comment: IMO, this is the best answer, because people find it hard to accept that the C standard leaves some behaviors undefined without a good example of the optimizations that this allows.

Answer (score 4):

POSIX defines the width and representation of `int64_t`, but the behavior of arithmetic operators such as `+` is defined by the C standard.  The C standard is clear that the behavior of arithmetic operators on signed values is undefined if the result would overflow.

Answer (score 4):

C11 6.5 §5 applies:

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined.

It is not the definition of the type that is the problem (even without POSIX, the exact-width integer types are already specified to use two's-complement by the C standard alone), but the operation 'signed addition' that results in an exceptional condition.

If you don't want that, use unsigned arithmetics instead. Note that if you want to avoid implementation-defined behaviour, the final conversion back to signed would need to be performed via type-punning instead of casting.

Personally I think that's overkill and would be fine writing the comparison as

```
(int64_t)((uint64_t)a + 1) > a
```

instead of going through the hassle of using unions or pointer casts.

Comment: The expression is not a division by zero or similar "mathematical" failure. The result is defined by the rules of "two-complement" arithmetic to be within the range.  You don't use integer arithmetic for doubles and your don't use floating point arithmetic for ints so do you have a pointer that says you should use the 'undefined signed integer' case when the type is most definitely defined?

Comment: @user3710044: but C arithmetics is not defined in terms of two's complement, but by abstract rules that in particular accomodate machines that raise exceptions on signed overflow; the representation of the integer value does not enter into the definition of the operation in any shape or form

Comment: @user3710044 The value of `INT64_MAX+1` is certainly "not in the range of representable values for its type". A 2's complement representation defines the result of operations which act on that representation, such as bit-wise and; but arithmetic addition is not such an operation. Do you have a source for addition being defined relative to the representation, rather than mathematical rules?

Comment: Two's complement is simply a way of representing signed values in the range -(2^(b-1))..2^(b-1)-1; it doesn't define anything about values outside of that range.

Answer (score 1):

The specification of 2's complement representation is important because C provides both bit-wise and arithmetic operations on the same type, and thus it is important to define the relationship between a variable's bit-wise representation and its arithmetic interpretation.

For example, setting the Most Significant Bit of a 2's complement integer to 1 (bit-wise operation) is equivalent to subtracting `INT_MAX+1` from its value (arithmetic operation).

These operations are not defined in terms of each other, though, they are defined according to mathematical logic. There is no such thing as "2's complement addition", because "2's complement" is a bit representation concept, and "addition" is an arithmetic one - the terms are from different domains.

As such, defining these relationships does not automatically define the result of individual operations which, within their own domain, result in values outside of the range of the type. For instance, a bit shift which requires more bits than have been defined in the representation is undefined, whatever its relationship to arithmetic value would be if it were possible. Within the domain of bit representation, the operation is simply impossible.

By the same token, an addition resulting in an arithmetic value larger than the maximum permitted by the type is undefined, regardless of what bit-wise operations would result if it were attempted. Within the domain of arithmetic, the result is well-defined, but impossible to store.

It is possible for a standard to define a behaviour for operations which are logically "impossible", for instance division by zero. In the case of overflow, a standard *could* define that this result in a "wraparound", affecting the most significant bits of the representation. Equally, it *could* say that this operation should result in a runtime error of some sort, or define it as resulting in the maximum possible value.

The C standard instead leaves this as undefined behaviour, meaning any behaviour a compiler chooses is equally valid, even if that varies at different optimisation levels or different parts of a program. In your case, there is no value of `a` for which asserting that `a+1 > a` is *incorrect*, so the compiler is free to assume that the inequality is true for all possible values, and simplify it at compile time.

Comment: Neither floating point nor unsigned addition follow pure mathematical rules.  For both of them the results are NOT the results you get from pure mathematics. Twos-complement addition is defined exactly as modulo addition using exactly the same hardware; that's why it was invented.

Comment: @user3710044 I've edited the answer a few times, so you might need to re-read. "2s complement adfition" is one possible answer to "how should the program behave if arithmetic addition overflows?" The use of that answer is *not* implied by the use of a 2s-complement representation at the bit level. For all values within its representable range, 2s complement is designed precisely to make it easy to give the correct arithmetic answer (e.g. to avoid having two unequal zeros).