# How to write int64=int32*int32 in a standard/portable and efficient way?

Tags: c++, c

Related:
[Is this treatment of int64_t a GCC AND Clang bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578540/is-this-treatment-of-int64-t-a-gcc-and-clang-bug/29578958?noredirect=1#comment47306355_29578958)

The only solution I can think of is to explicitly convert one of the operands to `int64`, forcing the product to be also at least `int64`.

But if done this way, then it's up to the compiler's intelligence to actually do `int64*int32`, or `int64*int64`, or ideally, optimize it back to `int32*int32`.

As discussed in the related question, assigning the result of `int32*int32` to `int64` doesn't change the fact that `int32*int32` already causes UB.

Any thought?

Comment: C and C++ are separate languages, but you've tagged your question with both. If you're actually trying to ask two separate questions ("How do I do this portably in C?" and "How do I do this portably in C++?"), then you should post them separately. If you specifically require a solution that is portable and well-defined in both, then please say so explicitly (and perhaps mention why, since that's not a common requirement).

Comment: I don't see how the question you mark as related is actually related to this one.

Comment: If your compiler does not generate optimal code for such a basic thing, you should probably look for another compiler for writing something performance critical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've already indicated how to do this in a standard, portable, and efficient way:

```
int64_t mul(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
    return (int64_t)x * y;
    // or static_cast<int64_t>(x) * y if you prefer not to use C-style casts
    // or static_cast<int64_t>(x) * static_cast<int64_t>(y) if you don't want
    // the integral promotion to remain implicit
}
```

---

Your question seems to be about a hypothetical architecture that has assembly instructions corresponding to the function signatures

```
int64_t intrinsic_mul(int32_t x, int32_t y);
int64_t intrinsic_mul(int64_t x, int64_t y);
int64_t intrinsic_mul(int64_t x, int32_t y); // and maybe this too
```

and, on this hypothetical architecture, the first of these has relevant advantages, and *furthermore*, your compiler fails to use this instruction when compiling the function above, and on top of all that, it fails to provide access to the above intrinsic.

I expect such a scenario to be really rare, but if you truly find yourself in such a situation, most compilers also allow you to write *inline assembly*, so you can write a function that invokes this special instruction directly, and still provides enough metadata so the optimizer can make somewhat efficient use of it (e.g. using symbolic input and output registers so the optimizer can use whichever registers it wants, rather than having the register choice hardcoded).

Comment: there is no good reason to cast the return value. Your compiler knows what type to return

Comment: @mfro: I have to cast one of the arguments, however, otherwise the product will be `int32_t`, thus losing precision and liable to overflow before being converted to `int64_t`. (or, I suppose, I could have made the argument `int64_t` directly, if i was in the mood)

Comment: But if you made the argument `int64_t` directly, then the compiler couldn't choose the first version of the intrinsic set automatically.  The way it is currently written is best.

Answer (score 5):

Built-in arithmetic expressions only exits for homogeneous operand types. Any expression involving mixed types implies integral promotions, and the arithmetic operation itself is only ever defined for and applied to homogeneous types.

Choose either `int32_t` or `int64_t`.

As you probably understand correctly, for both choices of type arithmetic operations (at least `+`, `-` and `*`) are susceptible to UB by overflow, but there can be no overflow when operating on two `int64_t`s which both can be represented as `int32_t`s. So for example the following works:

```
int64_t multiply(int32_t a, int32_t b)
{
    // guaranteed not to overflow, and the result value is equal
    // to the mathematical result of the operation
    return static_cast<int64_t>(a) * static_cast<int64_t>(b);
}
```

As an example, here is how GCC translates this to x86 and x86_64 on Linux (note the different calling conventions):

```asm
multiply(int, int):

// x86 (32-bit, "-m32 -march=i386")     x86-64 ("-m64 -march=x86-64")
// args are on the stack                args are in EDI, ESI
// return in EDX:EAX                    return in RAX

mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+8]          movsx   rax, edi
                                        movsx   rsi, esi
imul    DWORD PTR [esp+4]               imul    rax, rsi
ret                                     ret
```

Comment: OP is aware of this but seems convinced that the compiler is going to generate some gratuitous 64x64 multiplication construct to implement it.

Comment: @R..: Why "gratuitous"? What's the alternative?

Comment: By range analysis (or more likely in this case, a peephole optimization) the compiler should know the operands are both 32-bit and that a 32x32 multiplication operation suffices.

Comment: @R..: Do you find [GCC's generated code](http://goo.gl/k4WQcA) suboptimal?

Comment: No, AFAIK GCC does exactly the right thing. But OP is doubtful of relying on this.

Comment: [Corresponding x86-32 output.](http://pastebin.com/ss6eY2Zr)

Comment: Perhaps you could add those asm outputs to your answer to help convince OP that the compiler will do the right thing.