# C++ Performance: Two shorts vs int bit operations

Tags: c++, performance

What of this options have the best performance:
Use two shorts for two sensible informations, or use one int and use bit operations to retrive half of it for each sensible information?

Comment: Why don't you profile and find out? (But the answer would be separate `short`s, as bitwise operations tend to be expensive)

Comment: 1) System dependent. 2) Only way to know for sure is to benchmark.

Comment: Two `int`s may be even better.

Comment: Also, don't discount that doing the thing that is easiest and most streamlined to *use* has the effect that you can devote more mental energy to making the rest of your program better rather than having some tied up in keeping this detail straight. This can very well outweigh any benefit you might (if any) from this microoptimzation.

Comment: Are you on a really really really performance critical system such as embedded ones? In that case you'd need to precisely check the architecture docs (or specify it in this question prehaps). Otherwise, don't worry, it's extremely micro optimization.

Answer (score -1):

This may vary depending on architecture and compiler, but generally one using int and bit operations on it will have slightly less performance. But the difference of performance will be so minimal that till now I haven't written code that will require that level of optimization. I depend on the compiler to these kind of optimizations for me.

Now let us check the below C++ code that simulates the behaviur:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 100;
    short a = 255;
    short b = 127;
    short p = x >> 16;
    short q =  x & 0xffff;
    short y =  a;
    short z = b;

    return 0;
}
```

The corresponding assembly code on x86_64 system (from gnu g++) will be as shown below:

```
00000000004004ed <main>:
int main()
{
  4004ed:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004ee:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    int x = 100;
  4004f1:   c7 45 fc 64 00 00 00    movl   $0x64,-0x4(%rbp)
    short a = 255;
  4004f8:   66 c7 45 f0 ff 00       movw   $0xff,-0x10(%rbp)
    short b = 127;
  4004fe:   66 c7 45 f2 7f 00       movw   $0x7f,-0xe(%rbp)
    short p = x >> 16;
  400504:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  400507:   c1 f8 10                sar    $0x10,%eax
  40050a:   66 89 45 f4             mov    %ax,-0xc(%rbp)
    short q =  x & 0xffff;
  40050e:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  400511:   66 89 45 f6             mov    %ax,-0xa(%rbp)
    short y =  a;
  400515:   0f b7 45 f0             movzwl -0x10(%rbp),%eax
  400519:   66 89 45 f8             mov    %ax,-0x8(%rbp)
    short z = b;
  40051d:   0f b7 45 f2             movzwl -0xe(%rbp),%eax
  400521:   66 89 45 fa             mov    %ax,-0x6(%rbp)

    return 0;
  400525:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
}
```

As we see, "short p = x >> 16"  is the slowest as it uses the extra expensive right shift operation. While all other assignments are equal in terms of cost.

Comment: You missed integer promotion and sign extension. When promotion happens, promoting two separate `short`s to two `int`s is at least as expensive as doing it with two `short`s packed as an `int`. In this case, performance advantage of more aligned access of packed load will show up.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. But that also depends. For example, if you check the generated assembly code above, they are not affected by this problem. The promotion will happen if we are trying to add, multiply short and int data, I believe.

Comment: No, that is no the case. `short` is always promoted to `int`. That's why `(short)32767+(short)32767` is not UB.

Comment: The constants such as 1, 2, 10000 etc. are treated as ints (eg. sizeof(1) == 4).  But if we are doing something like short x = 12; short y= 13 ; short z = x * y , ... then x,y,z won't be promoted to ints.   Equivalent assembly instruction for"short x = 15;"  will be something like "movw   $0xf,-0x6(%rbp)"

Comment: Skipping the promotion is simply an aggressive optimization by your compiler, which is OK because the outcome is the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579112/how-to-write-int64-int32int32-in-a-standard-portable-and-efficient-way http://icecube.wisc.edu/~dglo/c_class/promo_conv.html