# Multiplication of two integers in C++

Tags: c++, int, range, long-integer

I have a pretty basic question, but I am not sure if I understand the concept or not. Suppose we have:

```
int a = 1000000;
int b = 1000000;
long long c = a * b;
```

When I run this, `c` shows negative value, so I changed also `a` and `b` to `long long` and then everything was fine. So why do I have to change `a` and `b`, when their values are in range of `int` and their product is assigned to `c` (which is `long long`)?

I am using C/C++

Comment: The ints are not promoted to long long before multiplication, they remain ints and the product as well. Then the product is cast to long long, but too late, overflow has struck. Having one of a or b long long should work as well, as the other would be promoted.

Comment: You should tag the programing language you're using cause different languages might introduce different behavior ;)

Comment: Depending on which machine and version of C you're using the size of an 'int' may change as well.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - you should make it all official and stuff and copy/paste that into an answer rather than have it slumming it out as a comment. :)

Comment: @JimBuck: why not ?:-)

Comment: long long c = ((long long)a*(long long)b);

Comment: long long c=(long long)a*b

Comment: @danludwig I usually prefer not to add tags in titles but it is [debatable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253028/1708801)

Comment: This is a duplicate of one of my earlier questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579112/how-to-write-int64-int32int32-in-a-standard-portable-and-efficient-way

Comment: In C++11 (or later) you can declare `c` to be of "type" `auto` and this will solve this issue, meaning: `auto c = a*b;` will assign the right value to `c`.

Answer (score 28):

The `int`s are not promoted to `long long` before multiplication, they remain `int`s and the product as well. Then the product is cast to `long long`, but too late, overflow has struck.

Having one of `a` or `b` `long long` should work as well, as the other would be promoted.

Answer (score 4):

For arithmetic operators the type of the result is not dependent on what you are assigning the result to but the types of the operands. For arithmetic operators the [usual arithmetic conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions) are performed on the operands. This is used to bring the operands to a common type, this means for types smaller than *unsigned*/*signed* int if the values can fit they are promoted to *unsigned*/*signed* int, in this case they are already both int so no conversion is required. See [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24371868/1708801) for the details on why.

What we have now is undefined behavior since signed integer overflow is undefined behavior, this is covered in the draft C++ standard section `5` *[Expr]* which says:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of
>   representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined. [ Note: most existing implementations of C++
>   ignore integer overflows. Treatment of division by zero, forming a remainder using a zero divisor, and all
>   floating point exceptions vary among machines, and is usually adjustable by a library function. —end note ]

Now-a-days we have sanitizers to catch these types of undefined behavior and using `-fsanitize=undefined` with both clang and gcc will catch this at runtime with the following error (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/72MXRnNPNz4xjaN4)*):

> runtime error: signed integer overflow: 1000000 * 1000000 cannot be
>   represented in type 'int'

For reference section `5.6` *[expr.mul]* says:

> [...]The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands
>   and determine the type of the result.

and section `5` says:

> Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands.61 Then the following
>   rules shall be applied to the promoted operands
>
> - If both operands have the same type, no further conversion is needed.

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of absurd, because the assembler instruction does always compute

int * int -> 64 bits long

so if you look at the machine code, you see :
**imul** 
that store 64bits into eax edx
then 
**cdq** 
that put the bit sign of eax into edx (thus losing the full 64bits result)
and then  eax edx are stored into the 64bits variable

and if you convert the 32bits values into 64bits before the multiplication, you get a call to the 64bits multiplication function for no reason

(I checked : it's not the case when the code is optimized)

Comment: I agree 100%. I learned about the integer promotion rules on my first job in 1992, and still this behavior  of C/C++ trips me up sometimes. FWIW, ARM assembler behaves similarly to the Intel assembly behavior you described. Multiplying 2 32-bit operands works fine when the destination is 64 bits. It is just the language rules that destroy the math.