# Why does implicit conversion of int to long long int give unexpected answer in C++?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I read that conversion from `int` to `long long int` is promotion and hence thought that there shouldn't be any issue as there is no loss of data, unlike the vice versa conversion.

But when I multiply two `int`s of large value and store it in `long long int`, it is showing me negative number.

Eg:

```
int a=1000000, b=1000000;
long long int c=a*b;
cout<<c;
```

The above code gives me a negative value. Can someone explain why?

Comment: This is because you use ints to make an operation which results in a return value which is also an int that might overflow and then you have the promotion which is already too late.

Comment: I tried the same with C where I used the "%lld" placeholder in printf for printing. Even then, it is showing me negative value.

Comment: possibly a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662792/multiplication-of-two-integers-in-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a*b` is still of type `int`. Once it's evaluated, the result is *then* converted to `long long int`. At that point it's too late to avoid overflow. Convert one of your values to `long long int` before preforming the multiplication. Try this :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 1000000, b = 1000000;
    long long int c = static_cast<long long int>(a)*b;
    std::cout << c;
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The multiplication is happening as an `int`, which overflows, giving [*Undefined Behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (in this case overflow, which is very normal - your combination of compiler+settings may even guarantee it), and *after that* the result is being converted to `long long`.

I think you want to do the conversion on one of the arguments *before* multiplication, so that the multiplication is performed using `long long`s:

```
long long c = static_cast<long long>(a)*b;
```

In this way, `b` will be promoted to `long long` before the multiplication takes place, and the whole operation will be performed safely, and with the desired result.

Comment: Overflows give undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Adrian Lis for signed integers, yes

Comment: It is defined for `unsigned int`, but not for signed.

Comment: @Ap31 that is much more specific ;)

Comment: @AdrianLis Note I said `int`, not "integer types`. I was as specific as I possibly could have been!

Answer (score 1):

Because multiplying two `int`s will result in another `int` that comes with all the overflow problems attached. This `int` is then (after the fact) promoted to a `long long int` which still means it's not what you want.

Promote at least one of the operands to have the other promoted and get the result you want.