# Why does addition of two variable types inside sizeof() return the biggest variable size value instead of their sum?

Tags: c++, sizeof

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    long b;

    cout<<sizeof(a+b);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is 8 (size of a long variable). Why doesn't it return their sum?

Comment: type of `42 + 42L` is `long`

Comment: If the expression `e` has the type `T`, `sizeof(e)` is equivalent to `sizeof(T)`.

Answer (score 16):

> the output is 8(size of a long variable)

Because of **Integer Promotion**.

According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion):

> the ranks of all signed integer types are different and increase with
>   their precision: rank of signed char < rank of short < rank of int <
>   rank of long int < rank of long long int

Therefore, `a + b` produces a `long` because `a` is `int` and `b` is `long` (rank of long is greater than int).

So, you have `sizeof(long)` which is **8**.

> why it doesn't return their addition

You may be looking for `sizeof(a) + sizeof(b);`

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no integer promotion involved in this case; just regular integer conversion.

Comment: @eerorika *Re: "just regular integer conversion"*: See *"Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands."* in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073296/10251345) post under usual arithmetic conversions. Also, under the Integer Promotion section, it says *"**Whenever a small integer type is used in an expression**, it is implicitly converted to int which is always signed. This is known as the integer promotions or the integer promotion rule."*

Comment: That is indeed my point. There are no operands of small integer types (which means smaller than `int`), so therefore integer promotion is not the reason for why the size of the result is what it is. Note that the linked post is technically slightly wrong. Promotion *can* be to `unsigned int` although that is rare.

Comment: @eerorika *Re: "There are no operands of small integer types (which means smaller than int)"* Aren't both `long` and `int` of **integer types**, where `int` is smaller than `long`? *Re: "linked post is technically slightly wrong"* I don't know but you can find the same point(*Otherwise, both operands are integers. Both operands undergo integer promotions*) quoted in the link I gave to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) in my answer.

Comment: `Aren't both long and int of integer types, where int is smaller than long` Yes, they are. `Otherwise, both operands are integers. Both operands undergo integer promotions` Consider an example rule: "Doors of all vehicles are opened". What would happen when the rule is applied to a motorcycle? Is the rule violated because no doors are opened? Not in practice, because there is an implied "if the vehicle has doors, then ..." Similar implication applies to the quoted promotion rule. Both operands are promoted *if a promotion exists for the type*. There are no promotions for `int` or `long`.

Comment: The conversion to common type occurs after the "promotion".

Comment: @eerorika *Re:  "if such promotion exists. There are no promotions for `int` or `long`"* Can't `int` be promoted to `long`? See the ranking criteria under Integer Promotion where even longs are included.

Comment: No `int` cannot be promoted to `long`, or any other type. The rankings are defined there so that you can understand what *"Integer promotion is the implicit conversion of a value of any integer type **with rank less or equal to rank of int or of a bit field of type _Bool, int, signed int, unsigned int**, to the value of type int or unsigned int"* means.

Comment: @eerorika I see, does it have to do anything with the terminology? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42396934/10251345) where the person said *"`int` is then (after the fact) promoted to a `long long int`"*. I believe the rankings would not have mentioned the longs without any reason. *Re: "The conversion to common type occurs after the "promotion""* You have used the double quotes, any reason? I like to learn new things!

Comment: Yeah. Everyone in that page are using the word wrong ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ To be fair, it doesn't make significant difference once one understands what the outcome should be. I used double quotes just because there is no actual change due to the promotion in this case. Rules say that operands are promoted, but it doesn't matter because there are no promotions for those types. Thus "promoted".

Answer (score 5):

[sizeof operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) returns the size in bytes of a `(type)` or `expression`.

`a + b` is an expression and `a` is promoted to `long` after implicit conversion that's why the result is `8` on your machine i.e. the size of the `long`.

For calculating the total size of multiple types and/or expressions, calculate them separately and use addition like this:

```
auto total = sizeof(a) + sizeof(b) + sizeof(c+d);
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no integer promotion involved in this case; just regular integer conversion.

Comment: @eerorika: Are you referring to this _if the target type can represent the value, the value is unchanged_ under Integer Conversions from the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)? Please share if it's from some other part of the docs. Thanks!

Comment: I refer to what you wrote `a is promoted to long`. It is not "promoted" to `long`. Conversion to common type is not a promotion. This is just a minor issue with standard nomenclature.

Answer (score 4):

The `sizeof` operator returns the size of the `type` you gave it, in bytes. Because you said `long` is 8 bytes i guess you are on `x64`. That being said, this is what happens:

If you have your numbers declared like this:

```
int a;
long b;
```

When you add them togheter, the expression `a+b` is evaluated as `long` type and thus `sizeof(a+b)` is the same as `sizeof(long)`. If you want to see the sum of their sizes you need two `sizeof`s:

```
sizeof(a) + sizeof(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

The sizeof operator does not evaluate the used expression as its operand. It determines the type of the expression and returns the size that an object of the type could have.

For example if you have the following code snippet

```
int i = 10;
std::cout << sizeof( ++i ) << '\n';
```

then the value of the variable `i` will not be changed.

From the C++ 17 Standard (5.3.3 Sizeof)

> 1 The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object
>   representation of its operand. **The operand is either an expression,
>   which is an unevaluated operand** (Clause 5), or a parenthesized
>   type-id....

To determine the type of the expression used in this sizeof operand

```
cout<<sizeof(a+b);
```

there is deduced the common type of the operands of the additive operator + using the usual arithmetic conversions.

As the rank of the type long is higher than the rank of the type int then the common type of the expression is long and the operator sizeof returns the size of an object of the type long.

Answer (score 1):

Because the resulting type of an arithmetic operation is the same as the type of the operands (after their conversion <sup>1</sup>), and being the same type, also has the same size. Addition is not a byte-concatenation operation that would result in bytes of both operands side-by-side in memory. There is no reason to expect the result type to have the total size of the operand sizes.

Consider a program adding integers in a loop. If you add a billion integers together, would you expect the result to be the size of a few gigabytes?

<sup>1</sup> Specifically, the operands are first converted to a common type; there are no arithmetic operations on mixed types. In short, the common type is larger of the two, which in this case is `long` whose size on your system happens to be 8 (and before that, there would have been promotion to int, if there was a smaller operand involved).

Answer (score 0):

Because of automatic type casting of `int` to `float`. When two incompatible datatypes are added the least precise data type is automatically casted to more precise data type.
In this case `int` has 4 bytes of memory and `long` has 8 bytes of memory(of course, depending on your system architecture) Thats why `int` is first casted as `long` before adding.