# data type conversion in the expressions of C++

Tags: c++, types

Let's consider the scenario. I declared

```
int n;
long int sum;
```

and consider expression `sum = (n*(n-1))/2;`

Is `n` converted to `long int` and then the multiplication is done, or does the multiplication happen first and then the truncated value (if it exceeds `int`) is converted to `long int` and stored in `sum`?

Comment: If `n` is signed and `(n*(n-1))/2 > INT_MAX` this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: No, conversion does only happen at the assignment, not for the calculation

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion

Comment: [Similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662792/multiplication-of-two-integers-in-c)